# wcstombs() has invalid output on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libc

I'm trying to port some old C/C++ code to android(latest version of NDK), but I'm struggling with function wcstombs(). This function returns wierd result on Android and I don't know why.

Look at this code (it's wcstombs() example from C++ reference)

```
  const wchar_t str[] = L"wcstombs example";
  char buffer[32];
  int ret;

  ret = wcstombs ( buffer, str, sizeof(buffer) );
  if (ret==32) buffer[31]='\0';

  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "dbg", "%d ... %s", ret, buffer);


// Application.mk
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

This code prints "2 ... w". It looks like the function stops, if it reads a zero byte from the string.

Is it normal? Is there any replacement for this function?

Thx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution to this problem. Application has to be linked against LLVM libc++ instead of GNU STL.
Application.mk should look like this:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

Comment: I wonder how changing C++ library can solve a problem related to a C function.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%ls", str);
```

Comment: snprintf() is not a replacement for the wcstombs(). You can pass NULL as as destination string to the wcstombs() and it should return the number of bytes that make up the converted string. So you can alloc proper amount of the memory for the converted string.

Comment: @zdenek you can use snprintf for an equivalent because snprintf returns the length of the non-truncated string. so use `char ch; int length = snprintf(&ch, 1, "%ls", inputString); char *output_str = new char[1 + length]; snprintf(output_str, 1 + length, "%ls", input_str);`

Comment: In my experience, snprintf "%ls" is just as broken as using wctombs/wcsrtombs on NDK r10e - which makes sense as they would be using the same internal implementation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Changing the STL library did not work for me.

However using this implementation did work.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/android/support/src/musl-multibyte/wcsrtombs.c

There is also crystax ndk, which is a replacement for the google ndk. It could be useful.

https://www.crystax.net