# wstring support in Android NDK application

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

In My android NDK application I can define wstring str = L"my string". It compiles and links fine.

While I am using __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "tag", "JNI got initialized ...%S", str);

This is printing JNI got initialized ...S, but I expect to print "JNI got initialized ...my string"

Note : I have APP_STL: = gnustl_static in my Application.mk

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Try %s instead of %S

Comment: Yes but I need to pass WSTRING, if I use wasting with %s it gives only the 1st char.

Comment: Basically this is a simple snippet, I need whole lot of wstring support in my NDK module. That is the primary problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Basically wcstombs() API was not working in android NDK. I wrote my own API and my issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 bugs in your code:

1. The `%S` format specifier is non-standard extension (from SUSv2). It instructs `printf` to interpret the argument as a `wchar_t*`.
2. You are passing a `std::wstring` object instead of a character string pointer. This is undefined behavior.

If you know that `%S` is supported on your platform, and you want to use this non-standard extension, you only have to fix your argument passing:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "tag", "JNI got initialized ...%S", str.c_str());
```

If you want to keep the code standards compliant, you have to use `%s` and either use a `std::string`, or convert from `std::wstring` to `std::string` prior to calling `__android_log_print`. Note, that you still have to pass a character string pointer (i.e. `str.c_str()`).

---

In case the above doesn't produce the desired result, due to `wcstombs` producing invalid output on Android, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25453867/1889329) for solutions.